# how to add multiple files in different directories into local repository

Tags: git, github

[image]enter image description here

[image]

I want to add multiple files in different directories into the same repository and push it to the remote repository.
But I am bit confused can somebody please help me out.

Comment: Do you know how to use `git add` ?

Comment: Maybe you should consider reading some basic tutorials about git, because you don't seem to know much about it. Check [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial).

Answer (score 0):

```
git add directory1
git add directory2
git add it/can/be/only/the/subdirectory
```

then to make sure this is what you want

```
git status
```

then

```
git commit
```

then

```
git push
```

however, for `git push` to work properly, you'd need so-called `remote` configured. Check `git remote --help` or docs on the website.

Running through some tutorials would be helpful too in order to get these commands into your coding habits.

HTH